# Question on top margin in chapter page

Tags: spacing, sectioning, amsbook

In my LaTeX template, there is a page contained the chapter part that is too far from top of the page like the following:

[image]

My LaTeX file uses `amsbook`: `\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{amsbook}`. This happened only in the chapter page, the others are normal.

My question is: how can I fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by "chapter page"? The beginning of a new chapter? Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thank Anke for this, I mean exactly the beginning of a new chapter. I will add the minimal working example.

Answer (score 3):

since you are using `amsbook`, the "sink" (the vertical distance) above the chapter title can be decreased by redefining the value of `\topskip` in the code that sets the title block.

here is the code from `amsbook.cls`, with the part to be changed indicated.

```
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  %% change the value of \topskip from 7.5pc to the desired value
  \global\topskip 7.5pc\relax
  \begingroup
  \fontsize{\@xivpt}{18}\bfseries\centering
    \ifnum\c@secnumdepth>\m@ne
      \leavevmode \hskip-\leftskip
      \rlap{\vbox to\z@{\vss
          \centerline{\normalsize\mdseries
              \uppercase\@xp{\chaptername}\enspace\thechapter}
          \vskip 3pc}}\hskip\leftskip\fi
     #1\par \endgroup
  \skip@34\p@ \advance\skip@-\normalbaselineskip
  \vskip\skip@ }
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  %% change the value of \topskip from 7.5pc to the desired value
  \global\topskip 7.5pc\relax
  \begingroup
  \fontsize{\@xivpt}{18}\bfseries\centering
  #1\par \endgroup
  \skip@34\p@ \advance\skip@-\normalbaselineskip
  \vskip\skip@ }
\makeatother
```

`\@makechapterhead` formats "regular" chapter headings; `\@makeschapterhead` does the same for the starred version.  `\topskip` specifies the sink to the main title, so it should not be reduced to zero; enough space must remain to accommodate the "chapter n" line.