# New chapter top margin is large

Tags: margins

Similar question to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107848/question-on-top-margin-in-chapter-page).

I have too much space from top to the start of the chapter heading. How can I fix this and make it just as the other pages. I use my university thesis stylesheet. I din't find any topskip in the stylesheet for adjusting the sink (the vertical distance) above the chapter title.

1. I am not able to figure out where is it that I can change this
2. how can I vary the distance between the chapter number to the chapter name
3. how do I know how much are my margin values set to ? Could anyone please point out are all these defined in my stylesheet.

[image]

**Stylesheet template: uhthesis11.sty**

```
    %  University of Houston PhD/MS thesis style -- modifications to the report style
% For LaTeX version 2.09
% 
% Author: Dimitrios Georgakopoulos (dimitris@cs.uh.edu)
% Modified by: Kyle Strom (kbstrom@uh.edu) August, 2009 (initials KS)
% Modified by: Abhilash Sukumari (abhilashsukumari@gmail.com) August, 2012
% The float and footnote macros bellow are stolen from the  Stanfford University thesis style. 

\typeout{Document Style Option `uhthesis' <31 Aug 90>.}

\long\def\comment#1{}
\comment{

Example of use:
    \documentstyle[12pt,uhthesis]{report}
    \begin{document}
    \title{Transaction Management in\\ Multidatabase Systems}
    \author{Dimitrios Georgakopoulos}
    \adviser{Dr. Marek Rusinkiewicz, Chairman}
    \firstreader{Dr. Farok Bastani}
    \secondreader{Dr. Paulina Markenscoff\\Computer Engineering Department}

    \makecoverpages
    \begin{abstract}
       This thesis tells you all you need to know about the concepts and methods involved in this research ... 
    \end{abstract}
    \begin{acknowledgements}
        I would like to thank etc etc etc ... 
    \end{acknowledgements}
    \makecontentspages
    \chapterpages

    \chapter{Introduction}
         ...
    \chapter{Conclusions}
         ...
    \appendix
    \chapter{A Long Proof}
         ...
    \bibliographystyle{ascelike}
    \bibliography{mybib}
    \end{document}

Documentation:
    This style file modifies the standard report style to follow the
    Dean's Office "Preparing your Thesis/Dissertation for Submission
    to the college of Natural Sciences and Mathematics: A Guideline".  

    The \makecoverpages command creates a copyright page (optionally),
    the title page and, and the signature page.  The \begin{abstact}
    command creates the abstract page.  The abstract itself should be
    included between a \begin{abstact} and an \end{abstact} command, 
    as usual. Your (optional) acknowledgments should be included in the 
    (optional) \begin{acknowledments} ...\end{acknowledments} section.  
    The \makecontentspages command produces the table of contents, the 
    list of tables (optional) and the list of figures (optional). Finally,
    the \chapterpages command sets the page style of the main body of 
    your thesis.

    The following commands can control what goes in the front matter
    material:

    \title{thesis title}
    \author{author's name}
        \degree{author's degree}{type of thesis}
                - e.g. \degree{Masters of Science}{Thesis}
                - if \degree is omitted,
                  \degree{Doctor of Philosophy}{Dissertation} is assumed
    \department{author's department}
        - Computer Science if omitted
        \college{the college or school the thesis is submitted to}  
                - College of Natural Sciences and Mathematics if omitted
    \adviser{the adviser's name}
    \firstreader{the first reader's name}
    \secondreader{the second reader's name}
    \thirdreader{the third reader's name}
    \fourthreader{the fourth reader's name}
    \fifthreader{the fifth reader's name}  
    \chair{Department chair}   
    \assocdean{Associate Dean of College}     
    \threereaderstrue or \threereadersfalse
        - print or don't print a third reader in the
                  signature page (true by default)
    \fourreaderstrue or \fourreadersfalse
        - print or don't print a fourth reader in the
                  signature page (true by default)
    \fivereaderstrue or \fivereadersfalse
        - print or don't print a fifth reader in the
                  signature page (true by default)                  
    \submitdate{month year in which the thesis is submitted}
        - date LaTeX'd if omitted
    \copyrighttrue or \copyrightfalse
        - produce or don't produce a copyright page (true by default)
    \figurelisttrue or \figurelistfalse
        - produce or don't produce a List of Figures page
          (true by default)
    \tablelisttrue or \tablelistfalse
        - produce or don't produce a List of Tables page
          (true by default)


    This style uses interline spacing that is 1.6 times normal, except
    in the figure and table environments where normal spacing is used.
    That can be changed by doing:
       \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.6}
       (or whatever you want instead of 1.6)
    Unfortunately, that command probably won't take effect unless it comes
    before the \begin{document} or after something like \small \normalsize.

    The example above shows the 12pt substyle being used.  This seems to give
    acceptable looking results, but it may be omitted to get smaller print.
}

% First thing we do is make sure that report has been loaded.  A
% common error is to try to use uhthesis as a documentstyle.
\@ifundefined{chapter}{\@latexerr{The `uhthesis' option should be used
with the `report' document style}}{}


% New page margins setup KS 2009
%%--------------------------------
\textheight 9in
\textwidth 6in
\oddsidemargin 0.5in 
\evensidemargin 0in
\topmargin 0in 
\headheight 0in
\headsep 0.0in
\parskip = 0.0in
\parindent = 5ex
%%--------------------------------

% Disallow page breaks at hyphens (this will give some underfull vbox's,
% so an alternative is to use \brokenpenalty=100 and manually search
% for and fix such page breaks)
\brokenpenalty=10000

%--- use package ``setspace'' instead KS 2009
% Use 1.6 times the normal baseline-to-baseline skip
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.7}



% Roman page numbers in cover pages 
\pagenumbering{roman}

% Redefine the macro used for footnotes to use single spacing
\long\def\@footnotetext#1{\insert\footins{\def\baselinestretch{1}\footnotesize
    \interlinepenalty\interfootnotelinepenalty 
    \splittopskip\footnotesep
    \splitmaxdepth \dp\strutbox \floatingpenalty \@MM
    \hsize\columnwidth \@parboxrestore
   \edef\@currentlabel{\csname p@footnote\endcsname\@thefnmark}\@makefntext
    {\rule{\z@}{\footnotesep}\ignorespaces
      #1\strut}}}

\def\degree#1#2{
    \gdef\@degree{#1}
    \gdef\@thesistype{#2}}
\def\@degree{\rm Doctor of Philosophy}
\def\@thesistype{\rm Dissertation}

%modify to engineering college (KS 8/09)
% Define college/school  -- default Cullen College of Engineering
\def\college#1{\gdef\@college{#1}}
\def\@college{\rm Cullen College of Engineering}

% modify to Electrical and Computer engineering (KS 8/09)
% Define department -- default Electrical and Computer and Environmental Engineering
\def\department#1{\gdef\@department{#1}}
\def\@department{\rm Electrical and Computer Engineering}

% modify to Electrical and Computer engineering (KS 8/09)
% Define degree -- default Electrical and Computer Engineering
\def\departdeg#1{\gdef\@ \departdeg{#1}}
\def\@departdeg{\rm Electrical and Computer Engineering}

% Thesis advisor and committee
\def\adviser#1{\gdef\@adviser{#1}}
\def\firstreader#1{\gdef\@firstreader{#1}}
\def\secondreader#1{\gdef\@secondreader{#1}}
\def\thirdreader#1{\gdef\@thirdreader{#1}}
\def\fourthreader#1{\gdef\@fourthreader{#1}}
\def\fifthreader#1{\gdef\@fifthreader{#1}}
\def\chair#1{\gdef\@chair{#1}} % KS 2009
\def\assocdean#1{\gdef\@assocdean{#1}} % KS 2009
\def\submitdate#1{\gdef\@submitdate{#1}}

% \author, \title in report
\def\@title{}
\def\@author{}
\def\@adviser{}
\def\@firstreader{}
\def\@secondreader{}
\def\@thirdreader{}
\def\@fourthreader{}
\def\@fifthreader{}
\def\@chair{} % KS 2009
\def\@assocdean{} % KS 2009
\def\@submitdate{\ifcase\the\month\or
  January,\or February,\or March,\or April,\or May,\or June,\or
  July,\or August,\or September,\or October,\or November,\or December,\fi
  \space \number\the\year}

\newif\ifcopyright 
\copyrighttrue 

\newif\iffigurelist
\figurelisttrue 

\newif\iftablelist
\tablelisttrue

\newif\ifthreereaders
\threereaderstrue

\newif\iffourreaders
\fourreaderstrue

\newif\iffivereaders
\fivereaderstrue

\newif\ifdoublespace
\doublespacefalse

%\def\baselinestretch{1}\@normalsize
     \ifdoublespace
        \def\baselinestretch{1.7}\@normalsize
      \fi


%Cover pages
\def\titlep{%
        \newpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
        \setcounter{page}{2}
        \ifcopyright \setcounter{page}{3}
        \fi
        ~\vskip0.5in% KS 2009

        \begin{center}
         \Large\uppercase\expandafter{\@title}
    \end{center}

       \vfill % KS 2009

    \begin{center}
        \rm A \expandafter{\@thesistype}\\
        Presented to\\
                the Faculty of the Department of 
            \expandafter{\@department}\\
        University of Houston

        \vfill % KS 2009

        In Partial Fulfillment\\
                of the Requirements for the Degree\\
        \expandafter{\@degree}\\
        in \expandafter{\@departdeg} % KS 2009

     \vfill % KS 2009  

        \rm by\\
        \@author\\
        \@submitdate\\
    \end{center}}

\def\copyrightpage{%
%   \newpage
        \thispagestyle{empty}%
        \setcounter{page}{2}
        \null\vskip2.5in
    \begin{center}
        \copyright \  Copyright by \@author, \@submitdate\\ %KS 2009
        All Rights Reserved
 %           \vskip.5in
    %            \underline{\@author}\\
%            \vskip.5in
     %           \underline{\@submitdate}
    \end{center}}

% Signature page
\def\signaturepage{%
      \newpage
      \thispagestyle{empty} % KS 2009
      \begin{center}
        \Large\uppercase\expandafter{\@title}
      \end{center}
      \vspace{.4in}
      \centerline{\shortstack[c]{\vrule width 2in height 0.4pt\\
           \@author}}
      \vfill
%      \vspace{0.15in}
%      \hspace{0in} \rm APPROVED:
      \leftline{ Approved:} % KS 2009
      \vspace{0.15in}
      \rightline{\shortstack[l]{\vrule width 3.0in height 0.4pt\\ \@adviser}}
 %     \vspace{0.15in}
       \vfill

      \leftline{Committee Members:} % KS 2009
 %    \vspace{0.375in}
     \vspace{0.15in}
      \rightline{\shortstack[l]{\vrule width 3.0in height 0.4pt\\ \@firstreader}}
      %\vspace{.375in}
      \vfill

      \rightline{\shortstack[l]{\vrule width 3.0in height 0.4pt\\ \@secondreader}}
  %    \vspace{.375in}  %\hfill
      \vfill

      \ifthreereaders
        \rightline{\shortstack[l]{\vrule width 3in height 0.4pt\\ \@thirdreader}}
        \vfill
      \fi
%      \vspace{.375in}

      \iffourreaders
        \rightline{\shortstack[l]{\vrule width 3in height 0.4pt\\ \@fourthreader}}
        \vfill
      \fi
%      \vspace{.375in}

      \iffivereaders
        \rightline{\shortstack[l]{\vrule width 3in height 0.4pt\\ \@fifthreader}}
        \vfill
      \fi
%     \vspace{.4in}

%      \rightline{\shortstack[l]{\vrule width 3in height 
%         %       0.4pt\\Dean, \expandafter{\@college}}}}
%                   0.4pt\\ \@assocdean \\ \expandafter{\@college}}} %KS 2009

    %-- modification KS 2009 ---------
    \begin{flushleft}\begin{minipage}[h!]{2.5 in}
        {\shortstack[l]{\vrule width 2.5in height 
                   0.4pt\\ \@assocdean \\ \expandafter{\@college}}}
    \end{minipage}
    \hspace{0.4in}
    \begin{minipage}[h!]{3 in}
        {\shortstack[l]{\vrule width 3.0in height 0.4pt\\ \@chair}}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{flushleft}
    %-----------------------    
}

\def\makecoverpages{%
    \ifcopyright\copyrightpage\fi
    \titlep
    \signaturepage}


%Abstract cover page
\def\abstractp{%
        \newpage
        ~\vskip0.5in% KS 2009
    \begin{center}
        \Large\uppercase\expandafter{\@title}
        \end{center}

    \vfill

    \begin{center}
        \rm An Abstract \\
        of a\\
         \expandafter{\@thesistype}\\
        Presented to\\
                the Faculty of the Department of 
            \expandafter{\@department}\\
        University of Houston

    \vfill

        In Partial Fulfillment\\
                of the Requirements for the Degree\\
        \expandafter{\@degree}\\
        in \expandafter{\@departdeg} % KS 2009

    \vfill

        \rm by\\
        \@author\\
        \@submitdate\\
    \end{center}}

%Abstract 
\def\abstract{
                \def\baselinestretch{1}\@normalsize
                \ifdoublespace
                \def\baselinestretch{1.7}\@normalsize
                  \fi

            \abstractp
            \newpage
            \begin{center}
        %   \Huge\bf Abstract
    \Large{\bf Abstract}  % KS 2009 other... \uppercase{\bf Abstract}
            \end{center}
                \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}}

\def\endabstract{
                 \def\baselinestretch{1.7}\@normalsize}

%Acknowledgements
\def\acknowledgements{
            \newpage
            \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgments}
                \def\baselinestretch{1}\@normalsize
                \ifdoublespace
                \def\baselinestretch{1.7}\@normalsize
                  \fi
            \begin{center}
      %      \Huge {\ }   \bf Acknowledgements 
           \Large{\bf Acknowledgements}  % KS 2009 other \uppercase{\bf Acknowledgements}
            \end{center}
            }

%\def\endacknowledgements{}


%%%%----- TOC, LOF, and LOT changes for college (KS 2009)
\def\tableofcontents{%
\newpage
\centerline{\Large\bf Table of Contents}
%\vspace{1\baselineskip}
\@mkboth{Table of Contents}{Table of Contents}
\@starttoc{toc}
}

\def\listoffigures{
\newpage
\centerline{\Large\bf List of Figures}
%\vspace{1\baselineskip}
\@mkboth{List of Figures}{List of Figures}
\@starttoc{lof}
}

\def\listoftables{%
\newpage
\centerline{\Large\bf List of Tables}
%\vspace{1\baselineskip}
\@mkboth{List of Tables}{List of Tables}
\@starttoc{lot}
}
%%%%-----

%\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}

%Table of contents
\def\makecontentspages{
        \def\baselinestretch{1}\@normalsize
        \ifdoublespace
            \def\baselinestretch{1.7}\@normalsize
        \fi
%   \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
    \newpage\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
    \iffigurelist
          \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
          \listoffigures
          \newpage
        \fi
    \iftablelist
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
          \listoftables  
          \newpage
        \fi
        \def\baselinestretch{1.7}\@normalsize}

%Chapter page definition
\def\chapterpages{
        % Put the page number on the top of the page
%        \def\@oddhead{\rm\hfil\thepage\hfil}
%        \def\@oddfoot{}
%        \let\@evenhead\@oddhead
%        \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot

    \pagenumbering{arabic}}

% Redefine \thebibliography to go to a new page and put an entry in the
% table of contents

%--- Change the name and location of the Bibliography title (needs natbib).
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}

\renewcommand\bibsection{\noindent \Large{\bf \bibname} \normalsize
\vspace{1\baselineskip}
}


%--- use package ``setspace'' instead KS 2009
% Single space for drafts 
\def\singlespaces{
        \def\baselinestretch{1}\@normalsize}

%modify float placement - KS 2009

\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\makeatother

%--- change chapter headings - KS 2009
\newcommand{\Chapter}[1]{\clearpage % put new chapters on a new page
 \refstepcounter{chapter} % manually increment the chapter number
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter \thechapter . #1}
\noindent \Large{\bf Chapter \thechapter . #1} \normalsize
\vspace{1\baselineskip}
}

\newcommand{\appndix}[1]{\clearpage % put new chapters on a new page
 \refstepcounter{chapter} % manually increment the chapter number
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix \thechapter . #1}
\noindent \Large{\bf Appendix \thechapter . #1} \normalsize
\vspace{1\baselineskip}
}

%That's all folks
```

**Packages: packages.tex**

```
% -------- Fonts ---------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
% -------- bibliography stuff -----------------------------------%
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\usepackage{natbib}
% ---- section  --------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{sectsty}

\sectionfont{\normalsize\bfseries\uppercase}
\subsectionfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
%\subsubsectionfont{\normalsize \itshape}
\subsubsectionfont{\normalsize \bfseries}
\chapterfont{\Large}
\chaptertitlefont{\Large}

\usepackage{indentfirst} % indents the first line after a section
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-1\baselineskip}
\setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{0in}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{0in} % no additional space between chapter entries in the table of contents

\setlength{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}{-1\baselineskip}
\setlength{\cftafterloftitleskip}{0in}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hfill\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hfill}

\setlength{\cftbeforelottitleskip}{-1\baselineskip}
\setlength{\cftafterlottitleskip}{0in}
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\hfill\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftafterlottitle}{\hfill}

\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0in}
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Figure }
\newlength{\mylenf} % a "scratch" length 
\settowidth{\mylenf}{\cftfigpresnum\cftfigaftersnum} % extra space 
\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{\mylenf} % add the extra space

\setlength{\cfttabindent}{0in}
\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{Table }
\newlength{\mylent} % a "scratch" length 
\settowidth{\mylent}{\cfttabpresnum\cfttabaftersnum} % extra space 
\addtolength{\cfttabnumwidth}{\mylent} % add the extra space
```

**Working example: Test.tex**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report} %font must be 10pt or larger - verify with your department rules
\input{packages}
\usepackage{uhthesis11}
\begin{document}
\title{\large Laser multi-spectral confocal microscopy for structured illumination imaging} % other modifiers \bf
\author{Abhilash Sukumari}
\submitdate{August 2013} % Month of graduation (not defense)
\degree{Master of Science}{Thesis}%Comment out for P hD thesis

\doublespacing % uncomment for double space drafts, and comment out for single (must be double spaced for final submission) %
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{9} %check to make sure the page number is set properly
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
\label{Intro and background}
\section{Example : This is a section}
This is a section
\subsection{Example : This is a sub-section}
This is a sub-section
\subsubsection{Example : This is a sub-sub-section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There are scattered questions on this site solving parts of what you're after: [Space before chapters and contents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39988/5764); [Space length between the chapter number and the chapter title](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88025/5764); [Distance between chapter title and text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11233/5764)

Comment: I am not a fan of downloading zip files, who knows what's in them... The titlesec package can adjust those distances. I am a big fan of the KOMA script budle of classes. Thex save much more space then the classic report, book, etc. classes. But probably not an option if you are using a template

Comment: and the zip file could disappear at any time.

Comment: Added the complete stylesheet here and the MWE. Hopefully it can help someone later.

Comment: Have you tried using \Chapter rather than \chapter? The style file explicitly defines \Chapter as a new command. Maybe you are meant to use that?

Comment: @cfr : yes that seems to fix the problem but as you see in the image the chapter number and the title name are in one line; it's not split into two lines. http://i.imgur.com/jD3DAeH.png

Comment: Well what is it supposed to look like? What do the rules say? You can alter the definition of \Chapter to do something like \noindent \Large{\bf Chapter \thechapter .\\#1} but it is hard to tell what you need it to look like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your document class uses the default `\chapter`-related settings (with small additions). As such, it's a straight-forward patch of the heading macros to correct for the spacing. Add the following to your document preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
% --- Patch \chapter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{50\p@}{\chapheadtopskip}{}{}% Space from top of page to CHAPTER X
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{20\p@}{\chapheadsep}{}{}% Space between CHAPTER X and CHAPTER TITLE
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{40\p@}{\chapheadbelowskip}{}{}% Space between CHAPTER TITLE and text
% --- Patch \chapter*
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{50\p@}{\chapheadtopskip}{}{}% Space from top of page to CHAPTER TITLE
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{40\p@}{\chapheadbelowskip}{}{}% SPace between CHAPTER TITLE and text
\makeatother
% Set new lengths
\newlength{\chapheadtopskip}\setlength{\chapheadtopskip}{20pt}
\newlength{\chapheadsep}\setlength{\chapheadsep}{40pt}
\newlength{\chapheadbelowskip}\setlength{\chapheadbelowskip}{15pt}
```

The above updates `\@makechapterhead` inserts `\chapheadtopskip` that defines the distance from the top of the page to CHAPTER X, `\chapheadsep` that defines the distance from CHAPTER X to the CHAPTER TITLE, and `\chapheadbelowskip` that defines the distance from CHAPTER TITLE to the text body. Their original values were `50\p@` (50pt), `20\p@` (20pt) and `40\p@` (40pt), respectively, and have been updated to `20pt`, `40pt` and `15pt`, just as an example.

Since you may be using `\chapter*` (used by the ToC, LoF and LoT), one would need to patch the `\chapter*`-related macro (`\@makeschapterhead`) as well, which I've done above.