# How do I get proper spacing after chapter title?

Tags: spacing, chapters, memoir

Typesetting a book with mostly unnamed, but numbered, chapters. Someone helped me make the below, but the errors I added myself. This is based on Memoir's "brotherton" style:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}

\newcommand{\numtodanishword}[1]{\ifcase\value{chapter}?\or first\or second\else ?\fi}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makechapterstyle{matheson}{%
  \xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}
    {\printchaptername \chapternamenum \printchapternum}
    {\printchapternum \chapternamenum \printchaptername}
    {}
    {}
  \chapterstyle{default}
\renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{\chapnumfont
\ifanappendix \thechapter \else \large\MakeUppercase{\numtodanishword{\value{chapter}}}\fi}
\renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{\centering\chapnamefont\large\MakeUppercase{chapter}}
\renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
\chapnamefont\centering\large\MakeUppercase{##1}}
\setlength{\beforechapskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\afterchapskip}{-10pt} % I think I done goofed here
}
\chapterstyle{matheson}

\begin{document}

\chapter{}

A numbered chapter.

\chapter*{test}

A starred chapter.

\end{document}
```

As you can see, the vertical spacing after the "regular" chapter is okay:

[image: Proper spacing]

... But look at the starred chapter:

[image: Wrong spacing]

I think the error lies in the `\afterchapskip` line, as I have noted in the code. To make matters worse, I have already typeset a lot of pages -- so I'm looking to get the same spacing that the current code gives -- but I want  it for starred chapters as well!

How to fix?

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
\setlength{\afterchapskip}{-10pt} % I think I done goofed here
```

to this that will solve the issue

```
\setlength{\afterchapskip}{0pt} % I think I done goofed here
```

Comment: But that will mess up the spacing after the "proper" chapters. I want that spacing unchanged.

Comment: This could help ? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149757/new-chapter-top-margin-is-large